# error: #1054 - Unknown column 'NOPL' in 'where clause'?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

Why does the query give me this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'NOPL' in 'where clause' ?

```
SELECT supplierprice.country, 
         supplierprice.networkname, 
         supplierprice.mcc, 
         supplierprice.mnc, 
         `288`.clientprice,
         `288`.ns, 
         client_list.currency
  FROM supplierprice
  INNER JOIN `288` 
  ON supplierprice.supp_price_id = `288`.net_id
  INNER JOIN client_list 
  ON `288`.clientid = client_list.clientid 
  WHERE `288`.ns <> `NOPL` ;
```

Comment: You are using the incorrect quotes, rather use `'` if you wish to specify a string literal

Comment: inner join 288, !!!. what this means? this is table nae?

Comment: String need to be enclosed in single quotes. So it should be `'NOPL'`

Answer (score 3):

because you use ` (quoting field / table / db quoteing) instead of **'**

i think **NOPL** is in your where statement a "string"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, followed a_horse_with_no_name 's comment.

```
SELECT supplierprice.country, 
         supplierprice.networkname, 
         supplierprice.mcc, 
         supplierprice.mnc, 
         [288].clientprice,
         [288].ns, 
         client_list.currency
  FROM supplierprice
  INNER JOIN [288]
  ON supplierprice.supp_price_id = [288].net_id
  INNER JOIN client_list 
  ON [288].clientid = client_list.clientid 
  WHERE [288].ns <> 'NOPL' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just consulting my magic ball and it says:

When you write `WHERE '288'.'ns' <> 'NOPL' ;` actually you compare column `ns` from table `288`, with `NOPL` which I assume is a table. You cannot compare column with a table, though you have to specify a column from it like that:
`WHERE '288'.'ns' <> 'NOPL'.'column_name' ;`

If `NOPL` is a column though, you have to specify from which table it is like that:
`WHERE '288'.'ns' <> 'table_name'.'NOPL';`

If you provide a scheme or image of your tables, the magic ball won't be needed and I can actually give proper answer.